# Can we have array type data in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can we have array type data in sql server 2008
currently i am using comma seperated value to be treated as array value

Comment: Why you need array in a sql query? What is your plan?

Comment: If you need this as a field in another table, it is generally a better idea to create a new table, with one row for each element of the array.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Not if you have thousands of (rows and) columns in each array.

Comment: @YvesR what is the problem with arrays in SQL?

Comment: @Matthieu No problem, just asked to understand the use case at that time before answer, meanwhile he got plenty of answers anyway.

Answer (score 9):

SQL Server 2005+ supports table-valued variables:

```
declare @arr table (col1 int)
insert @arr (col1) values (3), (1), (4)
```

These are equivalent to arrays.

Answer (score 7):

You can use instead: 
1. [Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) 
2. [Temporary table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) 
3. [Table variable (2005+)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx) 
4. [Table-valued parameters (2008+)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

User-defined tables:

If you want to learn more, this article is widely referenced:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Table-value parameters were introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: How does this help though? I'm looking for options to store arrays in a column too, and it looks like TVPs make it easier to send arrays to SQL server, but do not help solving the problem of actually storing the data.