# Is there a way to store array like data in a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that holds Test Questions. Each row of the table contains details of a question for a test for a particular user.

The user is presented with 3-5 possible answers and I would like to store details of the answers that have been checked in the row. I don't really want to add new rows for every answer as this would create a huge number of rows.

Is there a way that I can store something like an array of answers in a column in SQL Server? Presently I am storing the data as a JSON string but I remember that Oracle had some way to store array data and I am wondering if SQL Server has the same.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooo!!!!!!

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about huge numbers of rows. SQL Server has been built to handle a tremendous amount of rows. Also once you have the data as rows you can create nice queries to summarise and report on it much more easily than if it's stored in json or something inside a field.

http://www.xprogramming.com/Practices/PracSimplest.html

Comment: You might find this handy too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759244/sql-server-the-maximum-number-of-rows-in-table

Comment: @juergen - Nooo as in "no it's not a good idea" or "no as in it's not available"?  Have you checked out how Oracle stores array data in columns?

Comment: It's not a good idea as you are complicating something that the database can handle quite nicely using normal rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we have array type data in sql server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155393/can-we-have-array-type-data-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Your issue 'I don't want to store a huge number of rows' is a non-issue. This is how a a normalised design stores this kind of data. You can certainly store it in the way you wish but this will result in a LOT more visits to stackoverflow asking questions to get around this bad design.

Comment: I have worked on an educational system with over 40 million answers a year. I would stick with 3NF, it will be you friend as your system grows.

Comment: To clarify what others have already said regarding the desire to not store a huge number of rows: how are fewer rows (in this scenario) actually faster? Storing multiple data points in a single field increases complexity processing time due to needing to parse it. Filtering / grouping / indexing it will be much more difficult. And your maintenance costs will also go up as there will be more points of failure (hence ElectricLlama's statement about that design resulting in more questions posted here). Properly normalized models are quite efficient, even with hundreds of millions of rows.

Comment: "Array" or "List" in SQL Server is a **table** !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally denormallizing is not a good idea. It is **rarely** a good idea idea. However, it is sometimes necessary for performance reasons. So, if not too slow, don't even consider it.

If you make a secondary answers table in your case with the TestQuestionID (or whatever you call the answers for a single question) to be the clustered index, it won't be much of a performance difference at all compared to a denormalized table.

If I were denormalizing your descriibed table I would probably just create 5 columns in the table, You could also use an xml field, but all you are storing is 5 answers, so I would not use xml in this simple case.

Since you are asking this question, you are not really a seasoned professional (we all start as novices) and you should consult the local sql expert before you denormalize.

ADDED CAVEAT,

Since you accepted this answer, you really need to understand for certain that denormalizing is **almost always** the wrong thing to do. That is why everyone, including me, was trying to tell you. Don't do this without talking to your DBA -- if you don't have a local DBA (unfortunately all too common) take the collective advice, and don't denormalize. I can think of only 1 time n my career that I think denormalizing was the correct solution. And I have bitten by the bad design (forced on me) by innappropriate denormlazation on many occasions.

Comment: ...except for the obstacle of returning an aggregated view of number of (Correct Answers)/(Number of Answers) for a subset of identifying course location in a timely fashion for say a School, District or State.

Comment: Clearly you argue correctly against denormalizing 99.97% of the time  for reasons you give an example of -- However, there is still the performance problem, what do you do when you have done EVERYTHING ELSE and it still too slow? Not your opinion that it is too slow, but it is measurably too slow -- performance considerations are breaking your application and you HAVE TO make it faster. You bite the bullet  and denormalize and pay the consequences.