# Array types in SQL Server functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a possibility to create a SQL Server function with arrays as parameters, to use it as an IN condition?

```
CREATE FUNCTION NAME
    (@IDLIST ARRAY<varchar(32)>
    )
... 

    RETURN 
        SELECT ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION 
        FROM TABLE_XYZ 
        WHERE ID IN @IDLIST
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have array types, no. It does have `table` `TYPE`s though. [Creating a user-defined table type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-creating-a-user-defined-table-type)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have array type data in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155393/can-we-have-array-type-data-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: There's a [really good series of articles](https://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) on precisely this topic. Table-valued parameters are one popular solution, but there are others.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you can just `CROSS APPLY` the function with a single ID?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support array types, but you can pass through a table variable using Table Types.

**However, I don't think you need this here.** You can just use a scalar parameter, and `CROSS APPLY` the function for each row of the outer table.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.NAME
    (@ID varchar(32))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN 
   SELECT ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION 
   FROM TABLE_XYZ 
   WHERE ID = @ID;
GO
```

```sql
SELECT t.*, n.*
FROM OtherTable t
CROSS APPLY dbo.NAME (t.ID) n;
```

You can also do this against a table variable or a temp table.

Alternatively, if you have a hard-codeed list you can use a `VALUES` clause

```sql
SELECT t.*, n.*
FROM (VALUES
  ('a'),
  ('b')
) t(ID)
CROSS APPLY dbo.NAME (t.ID) n;
```